# Knockout bindings not updating class styles

Tags: class, binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out how to add and remove classes from html with knockout.

What should happen is that when I click truck, the button should update to be of class btn-red, and the car button should have it's btn-red removed.

I can see that the event binding is working because the alerts are triggered and the correct value is returned, but I can't get the view to update.

I've put together a really simple JSFiddle.net/N8GBB/11/ (stackoverflow won't let me post the link for some reason)
Here's the code I'm using in jsfiddle

```
<button class="btn" data-bind="css:{'btn-red':type()=='car'}, click: set_to_car">Car</button>
<button class="btn" data-bind="css:{'btn-red':type()=='truck'}, click: set_to_truck">Truck</button>
```

```
var vehicle={ 
    type:ko.observable("car"),
           set_to_car : function(){
        this.type='car'
        alert(this.type);
    },
        set_to_truck: function(){
            this.type='truck'
     alert(vehicle.type);        
    }};

ko.applyBindings(vehicle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your `type` observable correctly.

The `ko.observable` method returns a function so if you want to change its value you need to call it as a function with the new value as the argument.

```
var vehicle={ 
    type:ko.observable("car"),
           set_to_car : function(){
        this.type('car');
    },
        set_to_truck: function(){
            this.type('truck');  
    }};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYKJH/).

You can read more about [Reading and writing observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @nemesv, I had actually read the documentation, but didn't really understand the implications all in. Thanks for clarifying that.